# Buffered Image in jar file using java

Tags: java, file, jar, bufferedimage

Okay, I've tried many answers from different resources but my code still does not work. (and i dont really understand how it's suppose to work)

It goes like this, the folder containing my java files are under Desktop/code
and i have a package named package.name which contains a folder of all the images i am trying to load...

I need to make it a jar file but my program always says the file cannot be read, any helpful tips would be appreciated

So, "image" is folder that has all the pictures i need

This is my code for the painting of the images :

```
   g2.drawImage(getPicture("/package.name/image/"+1+".png"), x, y, 200, 200, null);
```

and I have a method for buffering the images:

```
public BufferedImage getPicture(String filename) {
        try {
            File fp = new File(filename);
            BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));         
            return pic;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to read file!", "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

whenever I try to run it in the terminal, my code just outputs the message dialog box, I've tries compiling it to jar file and it doesnt work as well.

Comment: *What* is the exception class and message ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew the exception is this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` right ?? (my crystal ball says you do)

You should load your image without dots `.` and only slashes `/` like that :

`g2.drawImage(getPicture("/your/package/name/image/"+1+".png"), x, y, 200, 200, null);`

Edit: You are getting `IllegalArgumentException` not NPE - this answer is still valid as the cause is the same - `null` returned from `getResourcesAsStream()`.

If your `image` directory is in the root of the context, then it is in `default` package, and you should ommit the `/your/package/name` and use only `image/1.png` for example

Comment: the dot is part of the name of the folder, should i remove the /package.name ?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by root of the context?

Comment: if you have package like `my.app.main` then your directories will look like that `my/app/main`. Root context is the tope level directory of your application so it will be a directory that contains `my` directory ;)

Comment: @XaelYvette so if i works for you, accept the answer, let my rep rise to the sky ;)

Comment: idk i am not using CLI for compiling java applications